# Natural scrolling doesn't work in evince

Tags: xubuntu, evince

I have enabled the Reversed scrolling option in the Mouse and Touchpad section of the Settings app. Natural scrolling is thus enabled everywhere in the system, with evince being the only exception. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs on all Gnome3\gtk3 apps, for instance Nautilus. The problem fixes by running gnome-settings-manager, but it is better not to do it. I got a lot of new bugs after it and removed it with all dependencies and cleared config files...